# How to emmit "draw" signal from function in GTK cairo

Tags: linux, gtk, signals, draw, cairo

I write GUI for my program.

My function make some calculations and receive array of data. I want to plot this data using cairo.

```
    //code of my function for calculation

    GtkWidget *darea;
    GtkWidget *box;
    darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (darea, 100, 100);
    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), darea, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), box, 0, 1, 1, 2);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", 
        G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL);
```

But "draw" signal doesn't emmit (on_draw_event callback function doesn't start). How I can emmit "draw" signal after calculations in my function? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`gtk_widget_queue_draw()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw) and pass in the widget you wish to redraw:

```
gtk_widget_queue_draw(darea)
```

This emits a "draw" signal for the entire area of your widget.

Answer (score 1):

'draw' signal is emited when a widget is redrawed, more detailed documentation can be found here: [gtkwidget - draw signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw)

Comment: Hm, can you explain me how to use these function? For example, if my callback function for draw signal looks like `void on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)`. But `g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw");` doesn't work

Comment: Try gtk_widget_queue_draw(): https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw